# Random number of FORM fields being prepared for database

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

I've found myself with the following problem: I have form with a random number of fields. (This is so users can enter their fellow team members's names -- and there's no set size for teams.) I need this inputted data to be formatted in preparation for being stored in a database.

The database structure is fine, it's just getting a random number of `$_POST`s and putting them into an array that's the issue.

So far I've got some javascript that allows the user to create/remove an infinite number of fields, with incrementing `id`s/`name`s (e.g. TeamMemberName1, TeamMemberEmail1, TeamMemberName2, TeamMemberEmail2, etc.).

Right now I've created an ugly series of PHP statements that puts a reasonable amount of `POST`ed data into a multidimenional array -- I don't see why a team should ever be bigger than 50 -- and then I was going to process the array to remove any blank rows before passing it onto the database.

Example:

```
    $submittedTeamMembers = 
      array ( "teamMember1" => 
          array ( "name" => $_POST["teamMemberName1"],
                  "email" => $_POST["teamMemberEmail1"])
             );
```

But I'm guessing there's a better way!

Comment: Why don't you set a second database table that connects teams. Ie table(team_id, member_id, memberInforUniqueToTeam) and you could also have a team table that has team information or have team be a non-unique column so if there are two people in team 3 then you have w rows (3, member_1) and (3, member_2).

Comment: I have a separate table for this already. The database structure isn't the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input names can be in array form, which PHP will understand perfectly.  Example:

```
<input type="text" name="teamMembers[0]['name']" />
<input type="text" name="teamMembers[0]['email']" />
```

which PHP will interpret after post as you'd expect:

```
//print_r($_POST['teamMembers']);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => foo
            [email] => bar
        )

)
```

Comment: Fantastic! This looks very promising! Thanks

Comment: Your answer is better than my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you.  It requires very little work to implement this which is why it's nice, and it's easy to name the fields properly using javascript.  This has made my life easier on many occasions by keeping my data structured without the need for a complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just give all your fields a name of 'TeamMemberName[]' or 'TeamMemberEmail[]'. Each should be posted regardless of whether or not the value is there, so they should always match up.

This will pass them as an array to your server-side PHP script, so you can access them like so:

```
$teamMemberNames = $_POST["teamMemberName"];
$teamMemberEmails = $_POST["teamMemberEmail"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($teamMemberNames); $i++)
    echo "name = {$teamMemberNames[$i]}, email = {$teamMemberEmails[$i]}\n";
```

Comment: I like @Crashspeeder's answer better.