# Different input name's

Tags: php

I have a form with input fields like:

post_1a ; post_1b  ; post_1c

post_2a ; post_2a  ; post_2a

post_3a ; post_3a  ; post_3a

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="new_post_a" name="post_1a" type="text"></td>
            <td><input id="new_post_b" name="post_1b" type="text"></td>
            <td><input id="new_post_c" name="post_1c" type="text"></td>
            <td><button id="add_row_btn">Toevoegen</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i want to catch with the post, but because this field are generate with javascript, i have tried to catch with preg_match/explode but results, i need the value of the input.

I cannot change the input name's because of the javascript.

does somebody has an idea becuase i have no ideas anymore?

Comment: You SHOULD change your input names.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469860/random-number-of-form-fields-being-prepared-for-database/9469956#9469956) should clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
// start with post_1a
$i = 1;

// while post_{$i}a (and ...b and ...c) is set, do ...
while (isset($_POST["post_".$i."a"], $_POST["post_".$i."b"], 
    $_POST["post_".$i."c"]))
{
    // do something useful with the three values
    var_dump(
        $_POST["post_".$i."a"], 
        $_POST["post_".$i."b"], 
        $_POST["post_".$i."c"]
    );

    // increment $i for the next 3 inputs.
    $i++;
}
```

If you can change the input's names, see [this article](http://jetlogs.org/2007/07/19/passing-input-arrays-in-php/) for a cleaner solution.

Comment: yes this is the solution I was looking for! Thank you! i will take a look into the link you gave, and i will try to change it.

Comment: I'm thrilled to know why this got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question as PHP, I am going to assume you are posting the form to a PHP file.

First off, I am not sure of your reason for naming the input fields "post_1a", "post_1b" etc, but Basti already answered above. However, depending on what you're doing with the data, it may be easier on the backend if you simply make them an array, then you would have:

```
<tr>
  <td><input id="new_post_1a" name="post_1[]" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="new_post_1b" name="post_1[]" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="new_post_1c" name="post_1[]" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input id="new_post_2a" name="post_2[]" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="new_post_2b" name="post_2[]" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="new_post_2c" name="post_2[]" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Then in the backend:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$post_values = array();

while ( array_key_exists("post_{$i}", $_POST) ) {
  $post_values = array_merge($post_values, $_POST['post_'.$i++]);
}
```